# referencing a servlet which is packaged from a jsp in a different dir

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

I am trying to call a Servlet within a jsp. But the servlet is packaged.

Servlet is here:

```
com.servlet.java.Cars
```

and in the JSP is in this dir:

```
com/servlet/resources/Cars.jsp
```

In the JSP form I do this:

```
action= <%=request.getContextPath()+"/com/servlet/java/Cars"%>
```

But when I run this I get no response from the servlet,as though the servlet printed nothing.

Comment: You must have mapped that servlet class to a name in your web.xml.  Try using that in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the Servlet `com.servlet.java.Cars` in web.xml with url-mapping `/com/servlet/java/cars`.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Cars</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlet.java.Cars</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Cars</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/com/servlet/java/cars</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your JSP, use it like below

```
<form method="GET" action="/com/servlet/java/Cars">
```

Comment: That is a pretty terrible mapping to have though.